# Ionic 2 chrome webview inspect not working

Tags: android, ionic2, android-webview, adb, chromium

I have Debian Stretch on my laptop, and fresh Lineage OS 14.1 (Android 7.1) install in my new phone without Google Play Services. I can run my ionic 1 app on my phone and I can debug it using Chromium's `chrome://inspect`, works pretty well, and it's very useful for me.

Now I made an Ionic 2 app for the first time. I can run it on my phone and my browser. I can also see my app listed in `chrome://inspect` but when I click on inspect, blank window opens. A few seconds later, I get `404 Not Found The resource could not be found.` message.

Right now, my both ionic 1 and ionic 2 apps are open. I can inspect the first, but get the error message for second.

Comment: Did your ionic 2 app work well in your phone?

Comment: @Duannx yes, it is running perfectly. I tried it with another very simple Ionic 2 app, same error in Chromium.

Comment: How do you build your app to your phone? Did you try with another phone?

Comment: @Duannx I run `ionic cordova run android`. I now tried with my old phone (CM 11 - Android 4.4.4) and it works as expected. I also seen it working with an Android 6.0 phone. So it might be a problem about newer Android versions?

Comment: I don't think new android versions is the problem. You should ask your question in [Ionic forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/). It is a better place for these questions like yours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use Lineage OS, you have to change in developer options "Webview implementation" from "AOSP WebView" to "Chrome Stable". Unplug the device and plug again. The inspector should now work propertly. :)

Comment: Nice. However I have Chromium installed instead of Chrome and there is no gapps. There is no other option than "aosp webview" right now. Can I enable chrome/chromium webview without installing chrome browser?

Comment: I think you have to install chrome on your desktop to inpect the device. I also have Lineage and is the only solution I have found to view inspector. If you find another one, do not hesitate to share it

Comment: Finally! I downloaded google webview from here: https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/android-system-webview/. Then in developer options in my phone, Google Webview appeared as an option. I selected it and now `chrome://inspect` works!